Homotopy Extension Theorem: Is 'Retract of an Open Subset' a Weaker Condition?
${1.4. \textbf{Theorem}}$
Let $Z$ be a closed subspace of a normal space $N$. Let $f: N \to P$ be a continuous map, and let $g: Z \times I \to P$ be a homotopy of $f|Z$. If $g$ extends to a homotopy of $f|U$, for some neighborhood $U \subseteq N$ of $Z$, then $g$ extends to a homotopy $h: N \times I \to P$ of $f$. In particular, this holds if $Z$ is a retract of an open subset of $N$.
This theorem is from Hirsch's Differential Topology, page 90. The statement seems clear, but I'm uncertain about the phrase: "In particular, this holds if $Z$ is a retract of an open subset of $N$."
I know that if $Z$ is a closed subspace of $U$, then the following are equivalent:

$(U, Z)$ satisfies the homotopy extension property (HEP).

$U$ strongly deformation retracts to $Z$, and $Z$ is a zero set in $U$ (i.e., there exists a continuous real-valued function on $U$ whose zero set is $Z$).


However, the condition here — "$Z$ is a retract of an open subset of $N$" — seems to be a weaker requirement. I searched for relevant references but couldn't find a clear explanation of this condition in the context of the theorem.
Could anyone clarify this point or provide some insight?
